# SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=table;reorg ;JOIN <joined_table>

Tags: db2

when running this query on db2 on DBeaver :

`reorg table departments`

i got this error (just on external channel):

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=table;reorg ;JOIN <joined_table>, DRIVER=4.19.49`

1. what does this query mean?
2. how can I fix the error?

appricicate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `call sysproc.admin_cmd('reorg table db2inst1.departments')`
as you are using DBeaver which is a jdbc application.

If you do not qualify the table name (for example, with db2inst1) then Db2 will assume that the qualifier (schema name) is the same as the userid name you used when connecting to the database.

DBeaver runs SQL statements, but it cannot directly run commands of Db2 - instead, any jdbc app can run Db2-commands **indirectly** via a stored-procedure that you CALL. The CALL is an SQL statement.

The `reorg table` is a command, it is not an SQL statement, so it needs to be run via the `admin_cmd` stored-procedure, or it can be run from the operating system command line (or db2 clp) after connecting.

So if you have db2cmd.exe on MS-Windows, or bash on linux/unix, you can connect to the database, and run commands via the db2 command.